# How to make a converter class correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, typeconverter

I have POJO data classes from API.

```
@Entity(tableName = "pokemon")
class Pokemon(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    val count: Int?,
    @SerializedName("next")
    @Expose
    val next: String?,
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    val results: List<Result>? = null
)
```

And class List:

```
class Result(
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    val url: String?
)
```

My database class:

```
@Database(entities = [Pokemon::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        private var db: AppDatabase? = null
        private const val DB_NAME = "main.db"
        private val LOCK = Any()

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            synchronized(LOCK) {
                db?.let { return it }
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    DB_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                db = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

    abstract fun PokemonDao(): PokemonDao
}
```

My class Converters:

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverters
    fun fromResultToString(result: slode.elsloude.pokemonapi.pojo.Result?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(result)
    }

    @TypeConverters
    fun fromStringToResult(value: String?): slode.elsloude.pokemonapi.pojo.Result? {
        return Gson().fromJson(value, Result::class.java)
    }
}
```

The error I get when attempting this is:

```
error: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods. - androidx.databinding.adapters.ConvertersC:\Users\elslode\.AndroidStudio3.6\PokemonApi\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\slode\elsloude\pokemonapi\pojo\Pokemon.java:22: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<slode.elsloude.pokemonapi.pojo.Result> results = null;
                                                                        ^C:\Users\elslode\.AndroidStudio3.6\PokemonApi\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\slode\elsloude\pokemonapi\pojo\SinglePokemon.java:14: error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@TypeConverters` annotation is used to link your converters with the database, as yuo have done here:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
```

However when declaring a converter method you should be using the `@TypeConverter` annotation:

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromResultToString(result: slode.elsloude.pokemonapi.pojo.Result?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(result)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromStringToResult(value: String?): slode.elsloude.pokemonapi.pojo.Result? {
        return Gson().fromJson(value, Result::class.java)
    }
}
```

*Note the plural on `@TypeConverters` vs `@TypeConverter`.*

---

Secondly Room cannot automatically infer a list conversion for you, so the type converter functions will have to map the full `List<Result>` to a `String` and vice versa.

Comment: Okey, thanks! 
my database still doesn't understand how to save this class to the database...

error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<slode.elsloude.pokeapi.pojo.Result> results = null;

you need to change the converter class itself, probably

Comment: You have to add a converter class for the `List<Result>` as opposed to just the `Result`. Unfortunately you have to handle that logic yourself!

Comment: thanks, very much! You've been very helpful

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make sure it's all in one place